# Lambda Expression in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, lambda

I am trying to lambda expression should be work in internet explorer. This code does not work on İE but it works on Chrome.

How can I use lambda expression by using function or sth else and call it here?
What should I do trying to work this code?

In below code: `(i, e) =>` does not work in `filter` method.

Can I assign ***lambda expression*** to variable or function?

```
var query = new RegExp($("#filter").val(), "i");
$(".list-item").hide().filter((i, e) => query.test($(e).text()));
```

Comment: **lambda expression** is called **Fat arrow function** in javascript. try running it in **edge**....!

Comment: IE <11 doesn't support arrow functions.

Comment: compile it to ES5 with babel. http://caniuse.com/#search=es6

Comment: The one you are referring to are called arrow functions. One reason that it works on Chrome and not in IE is because it must not have been implemented in the browser yet.

Comment: You can see the compatibility diagram [here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to change it using a callback with regular anonymous function:

```
$(".list-item").hide().filter(function(i, e){
    return query.test($(e).text());
});
```

Thing to note is that the IE browser which you are using might not implemented these ES6 features yet. So, better using a latest browser like chrome, Firefox, IE-edge etc.